# Landlord decided to do work after informing me the room was not supposed to be rent

Tags: england-and-wales, rental-property, landlord

My landlord informed me that my room cannot be let anymore because it is too small and he might get a fine from Barnet Council. He also told me to either move out or let him in to do building work in order to extend the room. I never approved him going in my room to do any work and today he informed me that he did. As a result, I cannot stay in my room and I am pretty much homeless for some days. He asked me to stay temporarily to another room he is renting you but he also informed that the previous tenant left it a bit messy.

What are my rights? [Citizens Advice](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/) only told me to contact [Shelter](https://www.shelter.org.uk/). I will need some advice to see how I can start and potentially pay a solicitor to take legal action.

a) Do I get a remuneration for all those months if he was renting a smaller room that he should have?

b) Do I get a remuneration for him entering my room without permission?

c) Do I get a remuneration for not being able to sleep in my room because of the building work? Note that he did that without me approving and without giving notice.

d) There are at least 4 rooms with unrelated tenants and as far as I am concerned he had an HMO (house in multiple occupation) license. But recently I read the rooms need to be of a specific size. More specifically, there are minimum space standards for rooms in HMOs used as 'sleeping accommodation'. Landlords cannot let out rooms below 6.51m2 to single adults and rooms below 10.22m2 cannot be let to two adults. Is there a penalty or a remuneration if they don't comply with that?

Comment: we need the jurisdiction

Comment: @TigerGuy The OP mentioned Barnet Council, which appears to be a borough of London, England.

Comment: You would definitely be entitled to legal aid. I would consider speaking to the NGO civil legal advice. I would specifically enquire about the possibility of getting a rent repayment order under the housing and planning act 2016.

Comment: The question would be whether violations of quiet enjoyment  alone if they don't rise to the degree of landlord harassment as such with the goal of pressurising you to leave are worthy of HAPA3016 RROs.

Comment: It's certainly worth contacting your council to find out if he actually was licenced or not.

Comment: I think that unfortunately for you it may be the case that when there's no license then he's rogue and lucky for you you can get a RRO. But if he has a license and is just not complying with it then at least he has a license so rendering him liable for council inspections, fines, enforcements etc so your only recourse might just be to contact the council and retort to to them to request enforcement from them.

Comment: You can check to see if an HMO licence exists [here](https://publicaccess.barnet.gov.uk/online-applications/search.do?action=advanced&searchType=Licencing).